# Are variable types permanent in Statically Typed Languages?

Tags: variables, types

My understanding is that variable types are "checked" before run-time for statically typed languages.

I take this to mean that a var of type int can't ever be type string? Does this mean variable type can't change (within the same scope) throughout the program (in a statically typed language)?

Somebody mentioned "variable shadowing" but I'm pretty sure that only applies in different scopes.

```
var i = 'hi';
function foo() {
    var i = 1;
}
```

My understanding of var shadowing is that `i` in the global scope is a different variable than `i` in the `foo` function scope and therefore their types are permanent and unrelated (in a static language, which JS is not). Is that right?

Comment: Isn't that what "static" means? As in, not "dynamic"?

Answer (score 1):

> Somebody mentioned "variable shadowing" but I'm pretty sure that only applies in different scopes.

It depends on your definition of "scope",  Rust, for example, allows the kind of shadowing that you're talking about, even within a single block:

```
fn main() {
    let a: str = "hello";
    let a: i32 = 3;
}
```

It could be argued that the declaration of a shadow variable implicitly ends the scope of the previous variable.  But to quote [from the Rust book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/first-edition/variable-bindings.html#scope-and-shadowing):

> Note that shadowing a name does not alter or destroy the value it was bound to, and the value will continue to exist until it goes out of scope, even if it is no longer accessible by any means.

Comment: so it would be incorrect to explain static typing to a beginner as having "permanent variable types" right? it's more or less true but there are exceptions...I'm trying to build a really simple definition of static vs dynamic.

Comment: @JBallin - A better way to think about static typing is that the type of an expression is known at all points by the compiler.

Comment: can you expand on that? my understanding was that at some point prior to run-time (im confused on when type checking actually occurs too - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47644075/when-are-variable-types-checked-in-a-statically-typed-language) it checks the variable types and then optimizes the compiled code based on that. am i missing something?

Comment: @jballin - I'm talking about basic compilation success/failure, not optimization.